# Jetpack Compose: How to change color of a button border depending on if it is enabled or disabled?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-button

Is it possible to change the color of the border `.border(` when it is disabled?
Something like `ButtonDefaults.buttonColors` to make border color `Color.Gray` if the button is disabled and keeping background transparent.

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    isEnabled: Boolean = true,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(40.dp)
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                color = Color.Red,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
            )
            .background(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        onClick = onClick,
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
            defaultElevation = 0.dp,
            pressedElevation = 0.dp,
            hoveredElevation = 0.dp
        ),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            contentColor = Color.White,
            disabledContentColor = Color.Gray
        ),
        enabled = isEnabled
    ) {
        Text(text = title)
    }
}
```

Comment: `color = if (isEnabled) Color.Red else Color.Gray` would be what I would try, given your current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a condition in the `color` attribute in the `border` modifier.

Something like:

```
.border(
    width = 1.dp,
    color = if (isEnabled) Color.Red else Color.Gray,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
)
```